# CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 9.0.0 or greater from App Store'

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic4, xcodebuild

I created an app in ionic and I wanted to test it in iOS. So I run the command `ionic cordova build ios` but, it is giving me the following error

I run this command for making a iOS build:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

```
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: 'xcodebuild was not
found. Please install version 9.0.0 or greater from App Store'
at cli.catch.err
    (C:\Users\RISINGBEE\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova:29:15)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: are you building using windows ?

Comment: yes, I m using windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build app from the apple devices but not from windows machine as per my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**

You need a Mac (Apple device) to build iOS

Check Ionic Doc [building iOS](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios)

Answer (score -1):

I deploy my app in Windows.
At the end i build my android apk and publish it under Google Store
Then i build my ios and i know that at the end of the process i have the same error as you. But it's not a problem.
After that i copy my platform/ios folder into my Mac where i finish the process from Xcode to publish my ios app under Apple Store
Bye